# What happens to the sentence order when you start the sentence with "auch"?

Tags: word-order

This is from a podcast transcription:

> "Auch sie(it) arbeitet regional..."

shouldn't then the verb precede the subject taking up the second spot in the sentence order?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on whether *auch* is an attribute of some part of the sentence or if it applies to the sentence as a whole.

In a sentence like

> Auch sie ist Lehrerin.

the *auch* belongs to *sie*: *She too is a teacher.*

Whereas in the sentence

> Auch ist sie Lehrerin.

the *auch* applies to the whole sentence so the meaning is quite different. This might be translated as *Also, she is a teacher* or *Apart from this, she is a teacher.*

This placement of *auch* has become a bit rare. Today many people would rather use *außerdem*.

Comment: Thanks a lot. "Auch" in front of the subject directly modifies the subject, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

"Sie arbeitet regional" --> She works regionally

"Sie arbeitet auch regional" --> (She usually works globally, but if necessary) she also works regionally

"Auch sie arbeitet regional" --> (like those people mentioned before) she too works regionally.

Comment: Your answer is succinct and well-rounded, thank you so much!